# Php web application long response time after running Powershell script

Tags: php, sql, ajax, powershell, iis

I'm writing a php web application hosted on iis web server and i'm actually trying to make a read-only powershell live web console.

This is how it works:
1) in my "console" main page i have a div and some buttons, the div starts empty
2) when you click a button, the click generates an ajax call to a page called "engines.php" and starts to load into my div the content of "engine515data.php"
3) "engines.php" first runs a query to delete some records from a XXX table, then runs a powershell script located on a remote server
4) this powershell script replaces some files (.dll etc...) on many different remote servers and inserts some records in the same XXX table
5) "engine515data.php" runs a select from the table updated by powershell script and echoes every row

Web app is running on IIS 10 with PHP 7.3

Ajax call in my main page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#515S').on('click', function(){
            var version = $(this).attr('version');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'engines.php',
                data: {runEngine: 1, version: version},
                async:true,
                success:function(data){
                }
            });
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                $('#show').load('engine515data.php');
                $('#clearConsole').on('click', function(){
                    $("#show").html("Console is ready and waiting for a script to be executed...");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                });
            }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Engines.php:

```php
function runEngine($version){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $db_server_name = "DB_SERVER_NAME";
    $remote_db_name = "DATABASE_NAME";
    $conn2 = dbconn2($db_server_name,$remote_db_name);
    $query="DELETE FROM XXX WHERE VERSION = '$version' AND UPD_TYPE = 'YYY' AND USERNAME = '$username'";
    if($conn2){
        $handle = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $psPath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
    $psDIR = "\\\\SERVER_NAME\\XXX\\XXX\\";
    $psScript = "SCRIPT_NAME.ps1 $version $username";
    $runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
    $runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript." 2>&1";
    $output = shell_exec($runCMD);
}

if(isset($_POST["runEngine"]) && $_POST["runEngine"]=='1'){
    runEngine($_POST["version"]);
}
```

engines515data.php:

```php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$server_name = "DB_SERVER_NAME";
$remote_db_name = "DB_NAME";
$conn2 = dbconn($server_name,$remote_db_name);
$query="SELECT Message FROM XXX WHERE (Version = 515) AND (UPD_TYPE = 'YYY') AND (USERNAME = '$username')";
if($conn2){
    $handle = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($handle, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if((strpos($row['Message'], "AAA"))!== false || 
         (strpos($row['Message'], "BBB"))!== false || 
         (strpos($row['Message'], "CCC"))!== false)
       echo '<font color="yellow">' . $row['Message'] . "</font>" . '<br>';
    else
       echo $row['Message'] . '<br>';
}
```

It worked with no problems until monday, then i suddently faced long response time and no more "live" records into my div.
The POST method to engines.php now take 90376ms (TTFB) to run and returns

> 500 - Internal server error

(after ajax call end i see what i expect into my div) but looking on SQL the .ps1 script runs smoothly, i see records i'm expecting.
I've tried to run the script directly from Powershell console while the div was refreshing and all runs smoothly with "live" records and no latency on respose time...
If i try to load the page that should retrieve the data from my DB (engines515data.php) while the ajax call is waiting the page continuously load showing nothing until the call ends and only then the div is filled with records and the page is loaded.
If i try to run, instead, a really light script (for loop writing "Test" 10 times) all runs with no problems.
I've also tried to remove some SQL queries and the while loop inside "engine515data.php" and to switch to an async ajax call but nothing changed.

I googled a lot and i already tried to change some config into my ini.php like "max_execution_time" or "memory_limit" and checked my iis application pool configuration but i cannot figure out what's wrong with my webapp. All i know is that THE SAME CODE was working perfectly until last week...

How can i avoid this huge response time?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: does your error log show any more details about the 500 error

Comment: `$output = shell_exec($runCMD);` is run in a function SCOPE! You do not return `$output` **Did you just change this code to put some of it in a function**?

Comment: About your first question: no, i have no further details about the error.
About $output yes i know it is in a function scope but i do not need the output of shell_exec function, it's there just to run powershell script above. That variable is not used in any part of my code

Comment: have you tried to analyze dump file with WINDBG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many search i found out that this problem is related to a php session lock, so i managed to solve it by adding `session_write_close();` in Engines.php between `$username = $_SESSION['username'];` and `$db_server_name = "DB_SERVER_NAME";`.

Thank everyone for trying, your effort was appreciated.